# 500 internal server error in joomla ckeditor

Tags: javascript, php, joomla

I have installed ckeditor in my joomla and it's working fine, except the uploading section. I got an error message

> 500 internal server errors The request was not completed. The server
> met an unexpected condition.
>
> mydomain/plugins/editors/ckfinder/core/connector/php/connector.php?command=QuickUpload&type=Files&CKEditor=text&CKEditorFuncNum=1&langCode=en
> (port 80)

while I am trying to upload a document. Also get this error message in the image uploading section. Does any one have an idea?

Comment: could be a lot of things without more information.  Do you have write access to the directories you are trying to upload to?

Comment: i gave write permission to the directories. My ckeditor version is CKEditor 3.0 (revision 4148).

Comment: Joomla questions are welcome at [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.